# How to configure Cached Exchange mode for Outlook using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ms-office, office-interop

I am working on a tool that needs to configure the Cached Exchange mode for outlook. I tried meddling with the registry but it seems like its not a good way to go about it, since in Outlook 2010 it is very unpredictable. Now, I am looking into either using Outlook Primary Interop Assembly or the Group Policy Assembly. I can find ways to read the current configuration but unable to set them. Is there a way to do it? Are there any other ways to accomplish the same?